# if and else loop in C #

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

My program fails when running some code I placed between 'if' statements.
I know why too much dependence on one task is to detect the
numbers <10 or >9
Numbers above 9 work, but a number with a single digit will cause an exception at this location:

```
            str = textBox23.Text;
            retString = str.Substring(1, 1);
            textBox22.Text = retString;
```

I'm guessing the if/else is poorly written, but I have checked with different variables, but it did not work. I don't really know what's happening
Here's the code:

```
private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (textBox23.Text == "" || Int32.Parse(textBox23.Text) > 9)

    {
        double L1 = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
        double L2 = double.Parse(textBox16.Text);
        double wynik = L1 - L2;
        textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();

        string str = null;
        string retString = null;
        str = textBox23.Text;
        retString = str.Substring(0, 1);
        textBox21.Text = retString;

        str = textBox23.Text;
        retString = str.Substring(1, 1);
        textBox22.Text = retString;

    }

    else if (textBox23.Text == "" || Int32.Parse(textBox23.Text)
    < 10)
    {
        double L1 = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
        double L2 = double.Parse(textBox16.Text);
        double wynik = L1 - L2;
        textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();

        string str = null;
        string retString = null;
        str = textBox23.Text;
        retString = str.Substring(0, 1);
        textBox21.Text = retString;

    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the text is blank?

Comment: google translate isn't quite there yet.

Comment: What is the problem? I don't get it.

Comment: What do you want this code to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Is this question worse or better written than the Code, that is the question ...

Answer (score 2):

you are changing the value of textbox23

```
textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();
```

any chance this value isnt 2 chars long, because latter you do

```
str = textBox23.Text;
retString = str.Substring(1, 1);
```

since substring is zero-based starting character you'll get an error if it isnt at least 2 chars

Answer (score 0):

you can use tryParse

```
private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Int32 IsAnumber;
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox23.Text, out IsAnumber)
{
if (IsAnumber > 9)

{
    double L1 = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
    double L2 = double.Parse(textBox16.Text);
    double wynik = L1 - L2;
    textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();

    string str = null;
    string retString = null;
    str = textBox23.Text;
    retString = str.Substring(0, 1);
    textBox21.Text = retString;

    str = textBox23.Text;
    retString = str.Substring(1, 1);
    textBox22.Text = retString;

}

else 
{
    double L1 = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
    double L2 = double.Parse(textBox16.Text);
    double wynik = L1 - L2;
    textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();

    string str = null;
    string retString = null;
    str = textBox23.Text;
    retString = str.Substring(0, 1);
    textBox21.Text = retString;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to obtain, however I'd go with this

```
int int23 = 0;

if (!int.TryParse(textBox23.Text, out int23)) 
{
   // manage error and exit function (via exception or return), test in here also string.Empty for textBox23.
}

if (int23 > 9) 
{
    // Do What you need
}
else if (int23 < 10) 
{
    // Do What you need
}
```

However once you got int variables, you can format directly them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this looks similar to what you are trying to achieve

```
    private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double box23;

        if (double.TryParse(textBox23.Text, out box23))
        {
            double L1 = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
            double L2 = double.Parse(textBox16.Text);
            double wynik = L1 - L2;
            textBox23.Text = wynik.ToString();

            string str = textBox23.Text;
            string retString = str.Substring(0, 1);
            textBox21.Text = retString;

            if (box23 > 9)
            {
                str = textBox23.Text;
                retString = str.Substring(1, 1);
                textBox22.Text = retString;
            }
        }
    }
```